# select rows in a table where date is between 2 dates in another row in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i would like to select a certain row in my table where date are between start and end date in another row in the same table.
my table is something like that.

```
============================================================================================
id         newid             start                 end                    date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             -            25/01/2018           26/02/2018            25/01/2018 
2            1            27/01/2018           27/01/2018            27/01/2018
3            1            05/02/2018           05/02/2018            05/02/2018
4            1            27/02/2018           27/02/2018            27/02/2018
============================================================================================
```

i create function to call result by id

```
function get($id){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix ."myTable";
$sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  $table_name WHERE id='{$id}'");
return $sql;
}
```

i would like the `$sql` return the result between `$id` start and end date
by using mysql not with php.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You can add a where condition like the following ''SELECT * FROM  $table_name WHERE id='{$id}' AND start BETWEEN '25/01/2018' and '28/01/2018'

Comment: @HariramanRadhakrishnan You can do that, but it won't help.

Comment: yes i know that but the start and end date changing every month to new dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name t1 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_name t2 
    WHERE t1.date >= t2.start 
        AND t1.date <= t2.end 
        AND t1.id <> t2.id
)
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b197a4/4/1

Now you can use the following PHP function (`get`):

```
function get($id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix ."myTable";
    $sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name t1 WHERE id = '$id' AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $table_name t2 WHERE t1.`date` >= t2.`start` AND t1.`date` <= t2.`end` AND t1.`id` <> t2.`id`)");
    return $sql;
}
```